# Unable to center UL in a class div with 100% width

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm making a website and can't seem to figure out a fix to my problem.

Here's the site link and css code:

http://mildsclan.com/newsite/index.html

http://mildsclan.com/newsite/styles/global.css

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I've tried a bunch of different display methods on the gallery-images, gallery-container and gallery div elements and even directly on the UL and LI ones. I also tried using floats, but they're a bit confusing sometimes.

Comment: It is always helpful to post your code here rather than link to it. Your request will be better received if users don't have to leave stack overflow to gain insight into your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to `.gallery-images` `width:88%; margin:0 auto;` If this is what you mean let me know if it works.